# Prove that for any graph G, there are at least $\chi(G)$ vertices with $degree\geq \chi(G)$ − 1.

Tags: graph-theory

Prove that for any graph G, there are at least $\chi(G)$ vertices with $degree\geq \chi(G)$ − 1.

$\chi(G)$ chromatic number of graph $G$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $G'$ be a $\chi$-critical subgraph of $G$. Then $G'$ satifies
$$\delta(G') \ge \chi - 1$$
Clearly $G'$ has at least $\chi$ vertices all of which have degree greater than or equal to $\chi - 1$.

Answer (score 2):

This is false; consider $C_{2n}$, $n \geq 2$.

Comment: I made mistake in inequality